# htaccess - redirect traffic from an URL to another 

Tags: security, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

Can anyone suggest how I can redirect any traffic the following path to another directory

```
images/flash/main.swf?config=/flash/flash_output/133/location.htm
```

this should 301 redirect to another URL (eg www.site.com)

The issue I get is the ? character which causes a problem with Codeigniter (version 2), as this causes the following error - The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
I am trying to use the htaccess file rather than the routes option in codeigniter to remedy the problem.

My current permitted uri chars config is below (the standard setting)

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

- I don't want to add the ? to this if possible here due to security concerns (the documentation states that this should not be changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `images` is a directory present in `documentroot`

Add this to your `.htaccess` in `DocumentRoot`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

Rewrite %{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING} images/flash/main\.swf\?config\=/flash/flash_output/133/location\.htm
RewriteRule ^ www.site.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Gaz Welcome. remember the aboce will work only with this URL: `images/flash/main.swf?config=/flash/flash_output/133/location.htm`